# jquery toggle working only if you click twice

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm implementing a tooltip thats triggered from an anchor tag and if you click the anchor we show the div right below it. I have the following code but you have to click the anchor twice for it to popup. Any ideas?

```
<script>
$('.tooltip-trig').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
</script>

<a href="#" id="test" onclick="return false;" class="tooltip-trig" title="">Tooltip</a>
<div class="test-tooltip tt-red-top" style="display: none;">
    <div class="title">Test</div>
    test
    <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="close">
        <span class="hidden">Close</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML from the page?

Comment: The only reason it would take two clicks is if it is already popped up before the first click.

Comment: Seems to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/c3AA5/

Comment: What browser are you using?  It works fine for me in chrome http://jsfiddle.net/xhybj/.  Also you are missing a quote after style=

Comment: once you clicked on it twice for first time.dose it act on one click then or it continue to work on clicking twice?

Comment: Seems fine here too, http://jsbin.com/agutug/edit - you may want to try adding $(document).ready

Comment: weird. once i click twice and it opens then it works on one click after that. I am using chrome.

Comment: Do the jsfiddles do the same thing or do those open on the first click? I'd also second @MoDFoX and say that this should be bound document ready, especially if the script tag is really before the html as it is in your pasted code above.

Comment: I actually have it in document.ready. that was a copy paste mistake. One interesting thing is the issue goes away when i change .toggle to .show